# insert multiple records recieved from JSON into a collection using mongoose

Tags: node.js, json, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have a big JSON array that inside of it there are a lot of objects. I want to insert this take this JSON and create a inside my DB for every object inside the array. I am new to MongoDB and mongoose so I am not sure about the approach. at some place I've read I need to use insert, in some I have read I need to use insertMany and in some I've seen create. currently nothing works. I am trying to do this like so (Get data is a private function that fetches a JSON from a remote api):

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require("../../models/NFTContract");
const Contract = 
mongoose.model("contracts");

let data= getData();
module.exports = app => {
app.get("/test", (req, res, next) => {
    Contract.create(contracts, (err, docs) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("err");
      } else {
        console.log("All should be inserted");
  }
});
```

});

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Read [these docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany) for some explanation on how insertMany works. Here is the example in the docs:

```
var arr = [{ name: 'Star Wars' }, { name: 'The Empire Strikes Back' }];
Movies.insertMany(arr, function(error, docs) {});
```

If you have a JSON, you want to parse it first. Let's say you have this JSON ([source](https://json.org/example.html)):

```
{"menu": {
    "header": "SVG Viewer",
    "items": [
        {"id": "Open"},
        {"id": "OpenNew", "label": "Open New"},
        null,
        {"id": "ZoomIn", "label": "Zoom In"},
        {"id": "ZoomOut", "label": "Zoom Out"},
        {"id": "OriginalView", "label": "Original View"},
        null
    ]
}}
```

If you want to insert the items, you would do:

```
Items.insertMany(JSON.parse(myJson).menu.items, (error, docs) =>
  error ? console.error(error) : console.log(docs))
```

Comment: For testing I have used a mixed schema. I have tried your code but nothing gets added to the collection nor I get any type of error on console